# asp.net mvc: check content type of the uploaded file 'text/plain' or 'text/csv', I always get application/octet-stream instead

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, mime

I want to verify the type of the uploaded file, 
that's how I do it:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ViewResult GetDataFromFile()
        {
            var file = Request.Files.Get(0);
...
            if (file.ContentType != "text/csv")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("FileInput.File", "The file uploaded is not in the correct format, please upload a csv file");
                return View("Index", new CandidateBulkInsertIndexInput());
            }
...
        }
```

but I always get application/octet-stream, anybody knows how to check if it is an csv or text MIME type ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting incorrect fileextension and content type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301535/getting-incorrect-fileextension-and-content-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that would be answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301535/getting-incorrect-fileextension-and-content-type/1301714#1301714).

Can you verify that the machine used to upload the file is aware of the MIME type text/csv?

Also try verifying on file extension.

```
var fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
```